# Logo with a link

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
#header .logo
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:39px;
    text-align:left;padding-top:10px;
}

.header_resize 
{
    width:960px;
    height:140px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
}

#header .logo 
{
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="home.html"><div class="logo"><img src="images/logo/logo.jpg"></div></a>
```

I don't know what is the issue with this code, when I click to a logo image it don't refresh the page and also it hides the logo image from the header. In IE it opens a new page in a header area only and rest of the page do not refreshes. I simply want a logo with a link, so that when I click the logo it refers to home page.

Comment: Is your header inside a frame or an iframe, or something crazy like that?

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an inline element, `div` is a block element. It is not valid to have a block element inside an inline element. Try this instead:

```
<a id="homelink" href="home.html"></a>
```

CSS:

```css
#homelink {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:39px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-image:url('/images/logo/logo.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

`remove` `div` tag and `add` class on `a` tag

**HTML**

```
     <a href="home.html" class="logo" >
      <img src="images/logo/logo.jpg">
     </a>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FVKVQ/1/)**

Comment: it works partially, problem now is that it don't refresh the whole page, it only refreshes the <div class="header_resize"> part and a complete page content appears in in this header div

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image: url('image')` in your CSS with HREF in your Division Box